# Show sub div of multiple parent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two `.class` elements and javascript code like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(".class-sub").show();
    // how to show .class-sub by button of this parent class
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <div>
    <a class="button">Click sub class1 class</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="class-sub" style="display:none">form class2</div>
</div>


<div class="class2">
  <div>
    <a class="button">Click sub class2 class</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="class-sub" style="display:none">form class2</div>

</div>
```

How can I show `.class-sub` by clicking a button of its parent class? I want to click `.button` and show the `.class-sub` of same parent.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("div.class-sub").show();
    // how to show .class-sub by button of this parent class
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1">
  <div>
    <a class="button">Click sub class1 class</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="class-sub" style="display:none">form class2</div>
</div>


<div class="class2">
  <div>
    <a class="button">Click sub class2 class</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="class-sub" style="display:none">form class2</div>

</div>
```

Use `.parent()` 2 times to get to parent div and use `.find()` to find the target div

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give the `.classX` elements a common class so that they can be found easily - I used `.class` in my example. The you can use `closest()` in the button click handler to retrieve them, then `find()` to get the related `class-sub` element. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        $(this).closest('.class').find(".class-sub").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class class1">
    <div>
        <a class="button">Click sub class1 class</a>
    </div><br />
    <div class="class-sub" style="display: none">form class2</div>
</div>

<div class="class class2">
    <div>
        <a class="button">Click sub class2 class</a>
    </div><br />
    <div class="class-sub" style="display: none">form class2</div>
</div>
```

Also note that you can use `toggle()` in place of `show()` if you prefer to display/hide the child element on successive clicks.

You could also use chained `parent()` calls without adding the `class` to the parent elements, but this would be very brittle code, and is considered bad practice for that reason.

Comment: Nice implement! Thank you so much